# 64-bit migration issue: pointer change

Tags: c++, migration, 64-bit

I'm using a [A Lightweight C++ Wrapper for Microsoft's ODBC API](http://www.drdobbs.com/database/a-lightweight-c-wrapper-for-microsofts-o/184416383) by [Ernesto Guisado](http://erngui.com/), although couldn't download source file from DDJ, I managed to find a copy on [github](https://github.com/mnjrupp/myodbc/blob/master/src/sqlodbc.cpp).

I could compile with current code in win32, but compiling in x64 hits an error

```
error C2664: 'SQLRETURN SQLDescribeCol(SQLHSTMT,SQLUSMALLINT,SQLCHAR *,SQLSMALLINT,SQLSMALLINT *,SQLSMALLINT *,SQLULEN *,SQLSMALLINT *,SQLSMALLINT *)' : 

cannot convert argument 7 from 'ULONG *' to 'SQLULEN *'
```

, basically can’t assign an `ULONG *` (`ULONG` is 32-bit), to `SQLULEN *` (`SQLULEN` is 64-bit).

What shall I do to make a smooth upgrade from ULONG, so that could have a 64-bit version?

Comment: both are pointers.

Comment: @TheTechel yes but one is pointing to a 32-bit ULONG, the other pointing to a 64-bit UINT64.

Comment: you should change the ULONG to SQLULEN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code expects a type to be equivalent to another that could be different, which is a bad practice.

To keep the class interface intact, you should change the function to something like this:

```
void SqlStatement::DescribeCol(USHORT number, UCHAR *name,
       USHORT BufferLength, SHORT *NameLength,
       SHORT *DataType, ULONG *ColumnSize,
       SHORT *DecimalDigits, SHORT *Nullable)
{
    SQLULEN tmpColumnSize; // store column size before converting to ULONG
    assert(IsValid());
    CheckStatus(::SQLDescribeCol(m_hstmt, number, name,
       BufferLength, NameLength,
       DataType, &tmpColumnSize,
       DecimalDigits, Nullable));
    if(ColumnSize) *ColumnSize = (ULONG)tmpColumnSize;
}
```

If the class interface does not matter, you could also replace ULONG by SQLULEN in the function.